# Какую структуру данных лучше выбрать?

Tags: c++

Задача заключается в следующем: вводим текст с клавиатуры, на выходе должны получить предложения построчно, причем в порядке возрастания длины предложения. Какую структуру лучше выбрать, чтоб в последствии было легче написать алгоритм сортировки?( Опробовал варианты `vector<vector<char>>` и `vector<string>`, но туплю в написании алгоритма сортировки по длине строки.

Comment: Что означает в ваших терминах понятие "предложение"? И какой алгоритм сортировки вы собираетесь написать?

Comment: предложение есть набор слов, состоящих из букв, и знак препинания: точка, вопросительный, восклицательный.

Comment: А как насчет алгоритма сортировки?

Comment: Как я ниже написал, проблема упирается в то, как при считывании string из нескольких предложений, запушбэчить их в вектор по одному

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Исполнение [на ideone](http://ideone.com/Ads7IW)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> Vec = {
    "Мама",
    "Мама мыла раму",
    "Мама мыла"
  };
  std::sort(Vec.begin(),Vec.end(),[](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    return a.size()<b.size();       
  });
  for(const auto &i:Vec) std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Мама
Мама мыла
Мама мыла раму
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло)

Comment: В принципе, @VladD это успел написать даже раньше. Я просто скомпиленный пример привел. Расти большой)

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего взять `vector<string>`. Для сортировки по длине используйте `std::sort` с компаратором.

```
vector<string> v;
// ...
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), 
     [](const string& l, const string& r) { return (l.length() < r.length()); });
```

Comment: Так и делал, проблема возникла в том, если за раз вводишь не одно, а несколько предложений в стринг, то как их потом по одному за пушбэчить в вектор?

Comment: @Freddy: А зачем вводить несколько в стринг? Вводите по одному.

Comment: @Freddy: Если их уже несколько в строке, ну так разбейте на куски, соответствующие предложениям. Но это уже другая проблема, не связанная с вашим вопросом о сортировке и структуре данных.

Comment: Это часть задачи. На ввод я обязан ввести сколько угодно предложений. Затем закидываю их в этот стринг, а стринг пушбэчу. Не могу сообразить, то ли стринг делить на предложения и частями пушбэчить, то ли как-то в стринг в процессе считывания их по одному заносить. Не знаю, как это реализовать.

Comment: VladD, все написал грамотно

Comment: @Majestio: У меня даже проверочный пример был: http://ideone.com/F1B7G7, точно такой же :)

Comment: )) Ну да, практически идентично. За исключением - я нэймсмэйсы не объявляю, и в `for` - `const` на автомате ставлю)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, то это задание на составление самостоятельно абстрактной структуры данных и ее сортировки.

В противном случае вы могли бы использовать контейнер `std::multiset`, в котором элементы сами бы упорядочивались по возрастанию длин предложений без всякой сортировки. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    auto compare = [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
    {
        return a.length() < b.length();
    };

    std::multiset< std::string, decltype(compare)> sentences(compare);

    for (const std::string & s : { "123", "12", "12345", "1234", "1" })
    {
        sentences.insert(s);
    }

    for (const auto &s : sentences) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Если вам надо разбить строку на предложения, то это можно сделать примерно следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    auto compare = [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
    {
        return a.length() < b.length();
    };

    std::multiset< std::string, decltype(compare)> sentences(compare);

    std::string text("I'm learning C++... How to write the program? I did it!");

    for (std::string::size_type pos = 0; pos != text.size(); )
    {
        auto last_pos = text.find_first_of(".?!", pos);

        if (last_pos == std::string::npos)
        {
            sentences.insert(text.substr(pos));
            pos = text.size();
        }
        else
        {
            while (last_pos < text.size() && text[last_pos] == '.') ++last_pos;
            sentences.insert(text.substr(pos, last_pos - pos + 1));
            while (++last_pos < text.size() &&
                (text[last_pos] == ' ' || text[last_pos] == '\t'));
            pos = last_pos;
        }
    }

    for (const auto &s : sentences) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
I did it!
I'm learning C++...
How to write the program?
```

Использовать для такой задачи контейнер `std::vector` не эффективно, так как он будет постоянно перераспределять память при добавлении нового элемента, а затем еще потребуется сортировка.

Если говорить о собственноручно написании структуры данных для хранения предложений, то постройте односвязный список. В него также добавляйте новые элементы в порядке возрастания ключей.

Comment: Благодарю!) сейчас покопаю методы!

Comment: `find_first_of(".?!;", pos);` иначе Кондратий Рылеев не парсится)))) http://stih.pro/je-vous-assure-chto-vi-mne-mili/ot/ryleev